# Associate a context menu with every item of a listbox bound to a collection of objects - Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a collection of objects which I want to display as a list. So, I'm binding a `ListBox` with this collection. All the items in the collection appear in the form of list. The next thing I want to do is associate a `ContextMenu` with every item on the list. (The context menu will basically contain a "delete" menuitem which will obviously delete the corresponding item.) Since I'm not making explicit `ListBoxItem`s, I can't understand how to associate a context menu with them.

Note: I have to bind the `ListBox` with the collection of items because I want the `ListBox` updated automatically when an item is removed from the collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put the ContextMenu in the concerned item using DataTemplate :

```
<ListBox>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ListBoxItem>
                  <TextBlock Text={Binding} > <!-- use the control you need, with the correct binding -->
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete item" Click="DeleteItem_Click" />
                                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                  </TextBlock>
             </ListBoxItem>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```